# Multithreading in JavaFX

Tags: multithreading, javafx

I need to work with multiple threads in background in a JavaFX application. I have a screen with ten buttons and I need to 'bind' each thread with the button that started the thread. If the user pressed a button that had started a thread (in the main screen, MainController.java), I need to recover it to display the information that contains to display it on the controls of Details Screen ( a second screen, DetailController.java).

What Class do you recommend for this? Service?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/package-summary.html

It is possible to name the threads with any of these classes?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick Overview of JavaFX Concurrency is explained with the  [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)).

Task and Service both implement the [Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html) interface, which offers many observable and FX thread safe properties. For example the [runningProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html#runningProperty) which you can bind to a `Button`s disable property, but there are many more to be used directly or [indirectly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) in your application.

The difference is, that the `Task` is for one time use:

```
Task<V> task = new Task<>();
Thread taskThread = new Thread(task);
taskThread.start();
```

After that you can not restart or reuse this task, you have to create another one. Because this is somewhat tedious, the `Service` was created. It allows to execute a `Task` multiple times (internally a new Task is created every time).

And, as you may have seen, you can assign ThreadGroups and every other `Thread` property by yourself when using the `Task`. These properties can be set for the `Service` too, but there you have to specify an Executor (where you can set the properties).

Comment: If that answers your question, please flag this answer accordingly ;)